# Change focus from form to input box in Excel App

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop, inputbox

I have coded a range selection input box in Excel, but I can't get the Excel application to become the focus, so the user has to manually click on the excel workbook to see the input box, then make the selection, hit ok and manually return to the Form.  Is there a way to programatically change focus?  I tried

```
xlapp.Application.Activate();
```

and read a bunch but can't find much.  Here is what I am working with:

```
 private void btnExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
        Excel.Workbook wkbk = null;
        wkbk = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook;
        Excel.Range address = xlApp.Application.InputBox("Select a Range", "Model Cutter 64", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 8);

        txtWkshtName.Text = address.Parent.Name;
        txtRange.Text = address.get_Address(address);
    }
```

I can provide more code if needed but this button is self contained, and doesn't reference and other code.

Comment: Have you tried `wkbk.activate` or `wkbk.cells(1,1).activate` or something along those lines?

Comment: @CBRF23 Thanks for the idea, but i tried a few variations and nothing at this point.  I feel like its going to be tough to shift focus out of the WinForm and back to it.  May just have to be done manually.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22779958/how-to-give-back-focus-from-console-window-in-c) yesterday:

I added this to the start of the program:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(HandleRef hWnd, int nCmdShow);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr WindowHandle);
    public const int SW_RESTORE = 9;
```

then added this snippet for the call:

```
private void FocusProcess(string procName)
    {
        Process[] objProcesses = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(procName); if (objProcesses.Length > 0)
        {
            IntPtr hWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
            hWnd = objProcesses[0].MainWindowHandle;
            ShowWindowAsync(new HandleRef(null, hWnd), SW_RESTORE);
            SetForegroundWindow(objProcesses[0].MainWindowHandle);
        }
    }
```

then called it using the name I found for the application in the Task manager and removed the extension.  So in my case I needed to bounce back and forth between EXCEL.exe and my program Model Cutter 64.vshost.exe.  I did so this way:

```
private void btnExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
        Excel.Workbook wkbk = null;
        wkbk = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook;
        FocusProcess("Excel"); 
        try
        {
            Excel.Range address = xlApp.Application.InputBox("Select a Range", "Model Cutter 64", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 8);
            txtWkshtName.Text = address.Parent.Name;
            txtRange.Text = address.get_Address(address);
        }
        catch
        {
            errorMessage("A valid range was not selected., please try again.");
            FocusProcess("Model Cutter 64.vshost");
        }
        FocusProcess("Model Cutter 64.vshost");
    }
```

Eventually, when I produce this I will have to remove the ".vshost" so that its just the name of the application, but in debug this works. I hope this helps someone else looking for an answer.