# Changing the focus back to the console window

Tags: c#, setfocus, windows-console, forth

My knowledge of Windows programming is close to zero. But now I have made a Forth program running from the console in Windows which opening a primitive window for graphics. The problem is that I want to control the program by pressing keys, but when the program starts there is no focus on the console window, just on the graphic window.

How do I change back focus? I guess I have to use some WINAPI, but which?

Comment: This what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22779958/how-to-give-back-focus-from-console-window-in-c

Comment: @JasonHeine: thanks! I will see if I can make it work.